# Using Gaq.Push to Track when a PDF is Opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am working on a website where there are multiple PDF's on the site. I would like to be able to track whenever a user opens a PDF, I tried doing this using the _gaq.push() method but without any luck.

Currently I have it set up like so:

All of my links are set up this way:

```
      <a href="docs/pdf.pdf" target="_blank" class="trackme" name="Download Specials">
```

and the code that sends the _gaq.push is pulled into every page:

```
     $('.trackme').click(function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PDFs', 'Opened', $(this).attr("name")])
     });
```

For some reason this has not been working and the research I have done has not really turned up any information as to what could be the issue. Does anyone know if there is a better way to do this or if its even possible?

Solved by adding

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'AccountNumber']);
```

to the top

Comment: solved it, I had to add
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'AccountNumber']);
to make it work, the guide i was following didnt mention that

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a syntax error. You're not closing the function:

It should be:

```
 $('.trackme').click(function () {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PDFs', 'Opened', $(this).attr("name")]);
 });
```

Comment: oops thx for pointing that out but that was more a product of me not pasting it properly. I found out the issue, ill post it above.